# CSS to force a container to properly fit around `<embed>` text, without introducing scroll bars?

Tags: html, css

I have a figure that contains an `<embed>` element:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Matroid Partitioning</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <style>
        *      { box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
        figure { border-style: solid; width: 90%; margin-left: 5%; }
        embed  { width: 100%; height: 44em; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <figure>
        <figcaption>Sample code for K<sub>19</sub>:</figcaption>
        <embed type="text/x-python" src="K19.code" />
    </figure>
</body>
```

Without the `width` and `height` attributes, the `<embed>` is rendered as a small rectangle with horizontal and vertical scroll bars.

Setting `width: 100%` eliminates the horizontal scroll bar.

But the only way I've found to eliminate the vertical scroll bar is to give a `height: 44em`, specifically set to the actual size of the text file.

This is obviously not a good solution (the file content could change, a narrow window might cause line-wrap and make it taller, the page could contain similarly embedded text files with differing heights, etc.).

I've tried playing with `overflow`, `object-fit`, and `height: auto`, but with no success.

I think this is independent of the container, so the question is simply:

**How can I get `<embed>` to fully display without a vertical scroll bar?**

---

If this is actually an X-Y problem, suggesting something other than `embed` for the text file would be fine too.